# The value of sine function repeats after every pi interval (zero value) and every 2 pi interval?

Tags: trigonometry

**sin 0 = 0**
sin pi/2 = 1
**sin pi = 0**

then why is it's period referred to as 2 pi in most books?

Comment: So $\sin(3\pi/2)=\sin(\pi/2+\pi)=\sin(\pi/2)=1$?

Comment: By the way, its period is $2\pi$ since $\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin x$ for all $x$.

Comment: The value $0$ happens to be repeated with a period of $\pi$, but other values do not.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at $\sin(1)$ compared to $\sin(1+\pi)$? (Or almost any other number in place of $1$.) Does that look like what a period should mean?

Answer (score 0):

A period of a function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is $L > 0$ such that $\forall x (f(x) = f(x+L))$, not $\exists x (f(x) = f(x+L))$.

In English, that reads that the function must be unchanged when you shift $x$ by $L$ for **every** $x$, not just for one $x$.

---

Note: "the" period of a function is the minimum such $L$.